# How to properly iterate or loop through an objects in react

Tags: reactjs

The code below queries a record from an Atlassian Storage API.

with `console.log(data)`   displays the records as objects objects.

with `console.log(data.first_name) and console.log(data.last_name)`, I can successfully see the  name **Lucy** and **Carrots** in the console.

**Here is my Issue:**

When I try to loop through the objects in other to display the records as per code below. it displays Error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.App**

If I remove the **projects.length**  and try to display records, it will show error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Below is my effort so far

```
import api, { route } from "@forge/api";
import ForgeUI, { render, Fragment, Text, IssuePanel, useProductContext, useState, Component, useEffect} from "@forge/ui";

import { storage} from '@forge/api';

 const fetchData = async () => {

//const data = {first_name: 'Lucy', last_name: 'Carrots' };

const data = await storage.get('key1');
console.log(data);
console.log(data.first_name);
console.log(data.last_name);

 };
 
 
const App = () => {
 const [ projects ] = useState(fetchData);
fetchData();

      
  return (
    <Fragment>
     <Text> Display Objects Records</Text>
     
 
         {projects.length ? projects.map((i, v) => (
          <Text key={v}>
            <Text>

<Text>First Name:  {v.first_name}</Text>
<Text>Last Name:  {v.last_name}</Text>
</Text></Text>

        )): <Text>No data stored yet...</Text>}
      

      
  </Fragment>
  );
};

export const run = render(
  <IssuePanel>
    <App />
  </IssuePanel>
);
```

Comment: what is this `const [ projects ] = useState(fetchData);` ? It is not the correct way to set the state. And please explain from where you're getting this `projects` array ?

Comment: your `fetchData` function does not update the state

Comment: Your API call had to be in useEffect(), the initial value of useState Can't be an API call. As the name says, useEffect is for side effects like API calls.

Comment: The result or record is displayed as an objects  not arrays something like `{first_name: 'Lucy', last_name: 'Carrots' };`  . I can get the First and lastname as I showed in the console.log but my problem is diplaying or rendering the records

Comment: you cannot use `map` on an object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the response data return an object, so you don't need to use `array` with `map`.

And you should call API in the useEffect.

```
  const App = () => {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await storage.get("key1");
        setProjects(data);
      };
    
      fetchData();
    }, []);
    ...
    {
      projects ? (
        <Text key={v}>
          <Text>
            <Text>First Name: {projects.first_name}</Text>
            <Text>Last Name: {projects.last_name}</Text>
          </Text>
        </Text>
      ) : (
        <Text>No data stored yet...</Text>
      );
    }
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks **@Viet** for getting back to me. I try to run your code but it displays error showed below  `Error: Error thrown in the snapshot context.
App code snapshot error: Snapshot error occurred: Error: cannot use a hook outsi
de of a component
Learn more about the snapshot context at http://go.atlassian.com/forge-snapshot-
context.
`

Comment: Put all it inside `App`

Comment: please Sir, How can I do that. please can you update your answer between Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])` instead of `const [projects] = useState(fetchData)`. This will make your state start out as an empty array that the API call can exchange for a filled one later by using `setProjects()`.

Then, inside `fetchProjects`, you can call `setProjects(data)` to update your state, which will rerender your page.

Finally, calling `fetchData()` in the place you do now will cause it to be called every time your App is rendered, which is inefficient.
Instead, call it inside a `useEffect()` hook:

```
useEffect(fetchData, []);
```

This will call `fetchData()` once when the page is loaded.